# Customize Table View for More View Controller in Swift?

Tags: swift, ios8, delegates, tableview, datasource

I would like to change the look of `More View Controller` which is being created when `TabBar` has many tabs.
So far, I've managed to access it in `AppDelegate` and change the look of its `Navigation Bar`. It looks like this:

[image]

However, I cannot seem to find a way to access and change the `TableViewController` that is being displayed in "`moreNavigationController`".

The best way for me would be to access it in a different Swift file, but When I create the `UITabBarController` file and try to access `UITableViewDataSource` it pops an error saying it does not conform this protocol (this is how I've managed to to this in Objective-C).

How can I access the `Table View` that's inside `More View Controller` ?

Answer (score 1):

The root view controller's view is the `UITableView` you're looking for, so that's exactly how you can access it:

```
UITableView* moreTableView=((UITableView*)[moreNavigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]).view;
```

Comment: As you can see from the picture, I already accessed TableView. The problem is getting DataSource to work. I have managed to do this in  ObjC but it seems suprisingly difficult to port this to Swift.